# Silverstripe 4: Include Template from Filepath

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm working on a Silverstripe 4 project where we need to include a SS template file from a path.

Here's a simple example giving the gist of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
class ExampleController extends ContentController
{    
  public function IncludeTemplateFromFilePath() {
    var $FilePath = '/path/to/file';
    ???
    return $output
  }
}
```

Template syntax:

```
<div>$IncludeTemplateFromFilePath</div>
```

I've had a look through the [SSViewer documentation](http://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/View/SSViewer.html) and looked at the Silverstripe source code but can't work out the correct syntax to make this work.

There are many examples of:

```
return SSViewer::get_templates_by_class(static::class, $suffix, self::class);
```

But what is the syntax to get a template from it's filepath?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do the following:

```
public function IncludeTemplateFromFilePath()
{
    return SSViewer::execute_string(
        file_get_contents('/path/to/Template.ss'),
        [
            'Content' => 'Value that will be in $Content when used in /path/to/Template.ss'
        ]
    );
}
```

Reference: http://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/View/SSViewer.html#method_execute_string